# Use java.util.Timer in swt

Tags: java, swt

This is my code:

```
new Button(shell,SWT.PUSH).addListener(SWT.Selection,new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()-start[0]));
                    start[0] = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            },100);
        }
    });
```

than I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:363)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.setText(Label.java:386)
at Main$2$1.run(Main.java:51)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

How to improve the code? ( except display.timerExec() )

Comment: Maybe this will help you : http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_do_I_get_an_invalid_thread_access_exception%3F

Comment: This is the most common error you get when working with SWT. Using google would have given you the answer in a matter of seconds...

Answer (score 3):

Try using asyncExec (not tested)

```
    new Button(shell,SWT.PUSH).addListener(SWT.Selection,new Listener() {
        @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                label.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()-start[0]));
                                start[0] = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },100);
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps

PS: Take a look at [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AGVdQis0obMC&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) book.